# How to track analytics event duration with Xamarin.Insights?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, analytics

I'm following `xamarin.insights` [documentation](https://insights.xamarin.com/docs) to track the event time:

```
using (var handle = Insights.TrackTime("FetchDataFromServer"))
{
    await FetchDataFromServerAsync();
}
```

My custom action was executed for 10 seconds but as a result I see the event without duration (I expanded the node):

[image]

How to get the event duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed. If you've been using TrackTime the data should be there. The Dashboard UI is the part that needed updating.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a known issue:
http://xamarininsights.uservoice.com/forums/267579-general/suggestions/6541283-timed-event-does-not-show-estimated-time

> This will be fixed this week